# React - How do I include a dynamic variable with ternary operator

Tags: reactjs

In JSX, how do I include a dynamic variable with a ternary operator? The below JSX gives unexpected token error, however if I replace `{x.title}` with a literal say `R` it works.

```js
let cardIDs = this.props.cards.map(x => <li key={x.title}>
{this.state.showName ? {x.title} : "S"}
</li>);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `{}`

```
{ this.state.showName ? x.title : "S" }
                       ^^     ^^
```